# Spring AspectJ AOP methods not executing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I am trying to add some pre-processing logic using AspectJ in my Spring MVC project. I have a `@Before` method and the corresponding PointCut in place. However, this method is not getting invoked at all when I invoke any of the methods matching the PointCut.

Here are my classes:

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ConcurrencyAspectConfig {

    @Before("execution(public * com.test.wms.service.dto.PackingDtoApi.*(..))")
    public void adviceMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("**** ASPECT START");
    }

}
```

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({SpringConstants.PACKAGE_SPRING})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

When executing any of the public methods in `PackingDtoApi`, I am expecting to see the `**** ASPECT START` message on the console. However, it seems that the Advice method never gets invoked. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you try having "@Component" annotation instead of "@Configuration" for  ConcurrencyAspectConfig?

Comment: @DragosGeornoiu Tried `@Component` as well. No help

Comment: Can you share the implementation of the class that you want to weave? Spring can only intercept interface based methods...

Comment: @TabishMir  is `PackingDtoApi` a spring bean ? could you please share the code that calls the public methods of `PackingDtoApi`

Comment: Without seeing the complete code , there could be three reasons primarily . 1. `PackingDtoApi` is not a spring bean 2. the invocation is an internal method call 3. `ConcurrencyAspectConfig` is not registered as a component. To confirm share a complete reproducible test case

Answer (score 0):

There could be mainly two reasons for your implementation to not work:

1. Wrong Pointcut expression - Double check your pointcut expression
2. PackingDtoApi is not a spring bean - Annotate the class with a stereotype annotation like `@Component`

**Note:** If this doesn't solve your issue, please share the code for
PackingDtoApi class